# Ошибка CS0103: Имя "..." отсутствует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#

Есть класс:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private string xml_P;
    public string Xml_P
    { 
        set
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(value))
            {
                xml_P = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PathException ("Некорректный путь", value);
            }
        }
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
 ...
```

Еще один класс:

```
class Risk
{
    private string id;
    public string ID
    {
     ...
    }   
    public Risk(string id, string v, string l, string p)
    {
        ID = id;
        V = Converter(v);
        L = Converter(l);
        P = Converter(p);
        R = V*L*P;
        XmlWriter(V, L, P, R, Xml_P); // Ошибка CS0103: Имя "Xml_P" отсутствует в текущем контексте
    }
```

Не понимаю, почему так, ведь свойство имеет модификатор "public", а значит - доступно другим программам и сборкам. 
[Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103) указывает на причину, но у меня пременная - глобальная и "public".

Comment: А откуда взяться этому значению? Вы его не передаете в конструктор. Класс Risk не является наследником.

Comment: Долго пытался понять что вообще вы имеете в виду. Поля с модификатором `public` не подразумевают под собой возможность вызывать их из любой точки проекта, а лишь дают возможность обратиться к ним, например, через созданный объект класса MainForm.

Comment: Извините за неточность. Я всего лишь начинаю. В данном случае как обратится. Прописать в конструкторе не могу ведь объект создасться после компиляции? Или вы хотите сказать, что так сработает: *XmlWriter(V, L, P, R, MainForm.Xml_P);*.

Comment: Я предположу, что вы немного не так понимаете фразу про "объект создастся после компиляции". В данном случае, лучше всего вообще вынести это свойство в другой класс, что бы не трогать лишний раз форму. Затем, в конструкторе `Risk` создать объект этого класса, к публичному полю которого спокойно можно будет обратиться (что то вроде `MyClassName class = new MyClassName(), а затем XmlWriter(V, L, P, R, class.Xml_P);`)

Comment: У меня в классе формы описан обработчик. использующий это свойство. Нельзя иначе исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во вторых, в старой редакции с# глобальных переменных как таковых нету вообще, и не появится ввиду особого устройства `с#`. Вы путаете с `c` `с++`

Во первых, вы не можете вот так брать из класса динамическую переменную. Поэтому сюда надо добавить `static`, а если есть динамические привязки - их надо как-то... убрать. Например так

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    static private string xml_P;
    static public string Xml_P
    { 
        set
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(value))
            {
                xml_P = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PathException ("Некорректный путь", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ещё оговорка - а **где ваш геттер**? Ну... ещё добавьте геттер сами, потому что и то что я написал работать не будет.

Только тогда можно делать фокус `XmlWriter(V, L, P, R, MainForm .Xml_P);` а используя новые фенечки c# последней версии можно опустить MainForm  если как-то по-особому в заголовках подключить его (это не означает что глобальные переменные появились).

P.S. Cтатическая переменная одинакова для всех эксземпляров класса, и ведет себя примерно как глобальная переменная в `с++`. И в `с++` статические переменные класса ведут себя аналогично.

Comment: Статическое свойство подразумевает то, что оно омеет значение одинаковое для всех объектов класса? И, к примеру, ссылки на `MainForm1.Xml_P` и `MainForm2.Xml_P` будут указывать на одно и то же значение в хипе? Если я не правильно вас понял, объясните понятия динамической и статической подвязки.

Comment: Да, статическая переменная одинакова для всех эксземпляров. Обычно обращение к ним делают через название класса. Хоть статику не рекомендуют, но для общих частей программы как данная - я считаю что она нужна.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно компилятор говорит.

Откуда этому полю появится если:

1. Класс Risk не является наследником
2. Класс Risk не является вложенным классом. Даже если бы был вложенным, то все равно бы словили ошибку, но другую, так как в конструктор не передается внешний класс.
3. В конструктор Класса Risk не передается этот параметр.

Comment: Если я передаю свойство как параметр, то ошибка не убирется. Ди и как вообще передать внешний класс в конструктор? Как передать объект типа какого-то класса видел. Приведите пример решения проблемы.